# App crashes when the popup window is called

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash

The popup window has to be shown when the app is started. The function that calls the popup window is located in the OnCreate() method. When I start debugging the app it constantly crashes.

```
    public void ShowPopup() {

       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mainactiv);
       dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
       dialog.show();
    }
```

And this is the error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.setContentView(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Can you please initialize your dialog before setContentView?

Comment: @AliYucelAkgul I am newbie to android development, can you please tell me how to initialize the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first initialize the dialog before using it.

```
public void ShowPopup() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);    // Initialize dialog before use
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mainactiv);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}
```